# Complications while converting an Android application to a library

Tags: java, android, aar

I had an Android application(MyApp, say) that used ApplicationContext extensively.  The ApplicationContext was made available via a class that extended Application.

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  static Context mContext = null;

  public void onCreate() {
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
  }

  public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
  }
}
```

I would like to convert this application to a library and use it in another application ( AnotherApp, say).   Now I see that AnotherApp already has a similar class that extends Application and gives its context everywhere within itself.  When I move MyApp as a library into AnotherApp, my code will not be able to get `ApplicationContext` anymore - as only one class can be declared in Manifest (`android:name=".AnotherApp"`)

What is the best way to make application context available within library?   I do not mind making extensive code changes, but would like to know options I have - other than passing context to every api in my library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done similar stuffs in my Application.

Its true you will not able to get context in your library
You will have context of only AnotherApp
If you want to use Context in your library in that case you need to have some method which can pass your AnotherApp's context to your library.

For example

```
class MyApp extends Application {

static Context mContext = null;

public void onCreate() {
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    objecofYourLibClass = new MyApp();
    objecofYourLibClass.yourMethod(mContext);
}

}
```

Now you will able to use context in your Library.

Comment: Thank you.   This is what I eventually did in short term.   Long term, as suggested by AJK below, it doesn't seem to be wise for a library to call getApplicationContext.   My problem was that my app was never designed to be a library.   BTW, did you mean class MyAnotherApp extends Application in your example?

Answer (score 1):

A library should never use the `getApplicationCOntext` it is meant for the main program.

you can pass the context using a function or save it into a public static variable in your class in the beginning.

---

**Note about code design**

This completely depends on how you want to use the library, will the functions be used in the main app ? Will the activity be directly called ? and a bunch of other code design things like that.

If you want two activities sometimes the best way it to make them into separate applications and make one call the other using an Intent. Like how google maps and other inbuilt services are used.

If you want to use your library's function in the main application, you should not be creating an activity at all. Rather you should make an abstract class that the user can inherit from and use your class through.

Comment: Agreed.  In the current form, a library using getApplicationContext is bad.   Wondering, if its a good idea for the platform to provide an api for the library to get applicationContext.